# Android Simple TextView Animation

Tags: android, animation, text, textview, zebra-striping

I've got a TextView that I would like to count down (3...2...1...stuff happens).

To make it a little more interesting, I want each digit to start at full opacity, and fade out to transparency.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 private void countDown(final TextView tv, final int count) {
   if (count == 0) { 
     tv.setText(""); //Note: the TextView will be visible again here.
     return;
   } 
   tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
   AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
   animation.setDuration(1000);
   animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
       countDown(tv, count - 1);
     }
     ... //implement the other two methods
   });
   tv.startAnimation(animation);
 }
```

I just typed it out, so it might not compile as is.

Comment: replace `tv.setText(count);` with `tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));` and code works fine

Answer (score 4):

I've used a more conventional Android-style animation for this:

```
        ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
        animator.setObjectValues(0, count);
        animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                view.setText(String.valueOf(animation.getAnimatedValue()));
            }
        });
        animator.setEvaluator(new TypeEvaluator<Integer>() {
            public Integer evaluate(float fraction, Integer startValue, Integer endValue) {
                return Math.round((endValue - startValue) * fraction);
            }
        });
        animator.setDuration(1000);
        animator.start();
```

You can play with the `0` and `count` values to make the counter go from any number to any number, and play with the `1000` to set the duration of the entire animation.

Note that this supports Android API level 11 and above, but you can use the awesome [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) project to make it backward compatible easily.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`CountDownAnimation`](https://github.com/IvanRF/CountDownAnimation/blob/master/src/com/ivanrf/countdownanimation/CountDownAnimation.java).

I first tried @dmon solution, but since every animation starts at the end of the previous one you end up having a delay after several calls.

So, I implemented `CountDownAnimation` class which uses a `Handler` and the `postDelayed` function. By default, it uses the alpha animation, but you can set any animation. You can download the project [here](https://github.com/IvanRF/CountDownAnimation).